# Matplotlib ylabel with subscript rotation does not work

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is a very simple problem but I cant seem to find the solution.

I want a subscript in my ylabel, so I used:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
pl.ylabel(u"$log(pKa_{pred})$",fontsize=28)
```

The ylabel is horizontal. Even after using `rotation = 'vertical'` it stays horizontal. 
Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks
VJ

Comment: `'vertical'` works for me, as well as `rotation=90`. What version are you using? Does it work with a simpler label?

Comment: It works with a simpler label. But once subscripts are added, vertical does not respond. I am using version 1.1.1. Thanks

Comment: I am using Matplotlib 1.3.1 and Python 2.7 64 bit and it works without problems...